# Pits in concrete slab foundation

Tags: concrete, foundation

Our slab foundation is 2.5 years old and Im seeing various small pits in the garage and patio like in the photo. Is this a concern with the structure of the foundation itself?  There’s also some pretty extensive cracks in the garage but I’ve always been told not to worry about those.  [image]
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spalling and Efflorescence](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/223633/spalling-and-efflorescence)

Comment: Or this? [What is this white powder on my foundation?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/99941/what-is-this-white-powder-on-my-foundation)

Comment: Are the pits new or always been there?  Pits(of a small/tiny size) usually not a concern except if they are new/developing.  Cracks in walls are a concern.  Is that a pit in the picture or a lump?  Cannot tell from the picture, but probably my eyes are seeing it odd.

Comment: Maybe pit is a wrong word, but there’s a chunk out of it. Almost like someone dropped a very heavy weight and took a chunk out of it.  It’s like it’s decaying in a few places. Also have several long cracks. Let me see if I can add another photo

Comment: The pits/dents  are new developing. Were not there when we closed on the house 2 years ago. They are just starting to appear.

Comment: How much winter do you get? My initial guess if things are not being dropped on it is "spalling" or freeze damage. As for cracks in garage slab, there should be molded or cut lines (control joints) to control where the inevitable cracks develop, and there should be but often isn't reinforcing steel to make the slab stronger (commonly ignored for residential and given the very small additional cost, the wrong place to save very little money.)

Comment: @Ecnerwal. We are in Texas and the house was built in late 2020 and in 2021 we had our snow apocalypse. Foundation was only about 6 months old

Comment: Thinking we might need to get someone out to evaluate since there’s quite a bit of cracking. The pits could be considered spalling although not in sheets like other photos.

Comment: Is this home built on a slab?   You say the issues are in the garage and patio .  Often these slabs are poured independent of the foundation and some cracks and even minor movement is normal here in Fla.  If there are no cracks along the walls, no doors or windows sticking, it most likely is not a problem.

Comment: @RMDman. Yes slab on grade but garages and patio are poured with foundation.  Driveway is poured separately.  Also, only driveway has the control joints. Not as common in the garages up here.  Also we are on clay soil so this makes me a bit nervous

Comment: @$Kiki,  garage and patio the only areas with issues?  Have any more pics?

Answer (score 1):

A few small pits could be attributed to air pockets when the slab was poured or dropping something heavy and pointed on it. You can fill them in with an exopy mix or concrete patch.

The cracks in the garage floor are minor at this time. Keep an eye on them.